# Tikz no border where rectangles touch

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks

How can i achieve, that the rectangles, where they touch, there is no black border.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6,yscale=0.5]
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,.-.1);
\draw (.2,.05) -- (.2,-.05);
\draw (.4,.05) -- (.4,-.05);
\draw (.6,.05) -- (.6,-.05);
\draw (.8,.05) -- (.8,-.05);
\draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
% Knoten unten
\node at (0,-.4) {$0$};
\node at (1,-.4) {$1$};

\newcommand\AONE{.5*0}

\newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
% U
\draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.2,3*\BLOCKHEIGHT);
\draw[fill=red!30] (0.2,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.1,2*\BLOCKHEIGHT);
\draw[fill=red!30] (0.3,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.1,1*\BLOCKHEIGHT);

\draw[fill=red!30] (0.6,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.1,3*\BLOCKHEIGHT);
\draw[fill=red!30] (0.7,0.2+\AONE) rectangle ++(0.1,2*\BLOCKHEIGHT);

\node at (-.1,.4+\AONE) {$S$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this manually by drawing the "contour" and then filling it with a color. However, one thing I've always liked about LaTeX is the ability to automate and let LaTeX itself calculate what to do, you just input the data.

To answer your question I created this command

`\meltedbars[ <options> ]{ <bar width / bar height>, ... }`

It works with your Tikz picture so `1` bar width is actually `0.1` on the axis. If you change the x and y for your Tikz picture, you will need to adapt the command appropriately.

As far as the options go, you can edit the style of both the line and the fill color. I've provided a couple of examples to show this and also different heights together

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    bar/.style n args={2}{fill=red!30, draw, inner sep=0, anchor=south west, minimum width=#1*6mm, minimum height=#2cm*\BLOCKHEIGHT/2}
}

\newcommand\AONE{.5*0} % I've included it because it's your code, but the result of this is currently 0
\newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}

\newcommand\meltedbars[3][]{%
    \foreach \BarWidth/\BarHeight [%
        count=\n,
        remember=\n as \lastn,
        remember=\BarHeight as \lastheight
        ] in {#3}{%
        \ifnum\n=1\relax%
            \node[bar={\BarWidth}{\BarHeight},#1] (bar\n) at (#2,0.2) {};
        \else
            \node[bar={\BarWidth}{\BarHeight},#1] (bar\n) at (bar\lastn.south east) {};
        \ifnum\BarHeight>\lastheight\relax% if nodes on the right are taller...
            \fill[red!30,#1,draw=none] ($(bar\lastn.south east)+(-.5\pgflinewidth,2*\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle ($(bar\lastn.north east)+(.5\pgflinewidth,-2*\pgflinewidth)$);
        \else % ...or if they aren't
            \fill[red!30,#1,draw=none] ($(bar\n.south west)+(-.5\pgflinewidth,2*\pgflinewidth)$) rectangle ($(bar\n.north west)+(.5\pgflinewidth,-2*\pgflinewidth)$);
        \fi\fi
    }
}

\newcommand\Xaxis{% so we don't have to type it every time
\node at (-.1,.4+\AONE) {$S$};
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\foreach \tick in {.2,...,.8}{%  you can do the ticks with a \foreach 
\draw (\tick,.05) -- (\tick,-.05);
}
\draw[thick] (0,.06) -- (0,-.06);
\draw[thick] (1,.06) -- (1,-.06);
% Knoten unten
\node at (0,-.4) {$0$};
\node at (1,-.4) {$1$};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6,yscale=0.5]
    
    \Xaxis
    \meltedbars{0}{2/3,1/2,1/1}      
    \meltedbars{.6}{1/3,1/2}

    % some extra tests
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
        \Xaxis
        \meltedbars[dashed, fill=green!30]{0}{1/5,1/1,1/6,1/4}      
        \meltedbars[densely dotted, fill=orange!30]{.6}{1/1,1/3,1/5}
    \end{scope}   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `rectangle`s, use line draws with relative lengths as original rectangles. Also use `\foreach` for any repeated segments.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=6,yscale=0.5]
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[thick] (0,.1) -- (0,-.1);
\foreach \x in {.2,.4,.6,.8}
  \draw (\x,.05) -- (\x,-.05);
\draw[thick] (1,.1) -- (1,.-.1);
% Knoten unten
\node at (0,-.4) {$0$};
\node at (1,-.4) {$1$};

\newcommand\AONE{.5*0}

\newcommand\BLOCKHEIGHT{0.4}
% U
\draw[fill=red!30] (0,0.2+\AONE) --++(0,3*\BLOCKHEIGHT) --++(0.2,0)
                   --++(0,-1*\BLOCKHEIGHT) --++(0.1,0) --++(0,-1*\BLOCKHEIGHT)
                   --++(0.1,0) --++(0,-1*\BLOCKHEIGHT) --cycle;

\draw[fill=red!30] (0.6,0.2+\AONE) --++(0,3*\BLOCKHEIGHT) --++(0.1,0)
                   --++(0,-1*\BLOCKHEIGHT) --++(0.1,0) --++(0,-2*\BLOCKHEIGHT)--cycle;
                                     
\node at (-.1,.4+\AONE) {$S$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An example showing the adjustment manually removing the center line between two nodes with a  line same color as fill

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node [style={draw,fill=red!30,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.5cm}] (1) at (0,  0)  { $1$ };
\node [style={draw,fill=red!30,  inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.5cm}] (2) at (0.5,  0)  { $2$ };
\draw[red!30,line width=1pt,shorten <=0.4pt, shorten >=0.4pt](1.north east)--(1.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

**OR**

[image]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node [style={draw,fill=red!30, rectangle,}] (1) at (0,  0)  { $1$ };
\node [style={draw,fill=red!30, rectangle,}, right=0.0cm of 1, yshift=-4pt] (2)  { $2$ };
\draw[red!30,line width=1pt,shorten <=0.4pt, shorten >=0.4pt](2.north west)--(1.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```